# Order of linked libraries in ocamlbuild

Tags: linker, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm having an issue with the order in which the libraries are added to the linker. Previously built libraries by ocamlbuild are linked in after the list of libraries I included by the `flag` rule. And, I don't see any way to define this type of dependency in `myocamlbuild.ml` either.

Specifically, the issue comes in linking with a previously built library (`gzcaml`) that requires a library itself (`z`). Because of the added strictness in newer versions of gcc the argument `-lz` must appear after `libgzcaml.a`.

I am including all these libraries with,

```
flag ["ocaml"; "link"]
    (S (process "-cclib" clibs))
```

where `process` creates a list alternating the library and `A"-cclib"`, appropriately.

Also, additional libraries are appended (from the verbose output, `-lm` and `-ldl`) but I have no idea how I can modify/append these? (this would instantly solve my problem).

My `myocamlbuild.ml` is quite long else I would have included it here. I have tried moving the above code around to the bottom of the `After_rules`, to the top. And it does change the order, but never after the built libraries (c and otherwise) that ocamlbuild created previously.

---

*EDIT*
Below are code snippets I've used in my configure script and ocamlbuild to solve the issue above. Cheers!

in `configure.ac`

```
oCFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
CFLAGS="$FLAGS -Wl,--no-as-needed"
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether we need to add --no-as-needed linking option])
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[]], 
                                     [[ 
                                        int main(){ return 0; } 
                                    ]])], 
                  [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes]); CC_NOASNEEDED="true"],
                  [AC_MSG_RESULT([no]); CC_NOASNEEDED="false"]) 
CFLAGS=$oCFLAGS
```

in `myocamlbuild.ml.in`

```
 if @CC_NOASNEEDED@ then
     flag ["ocaml"; "link"]
         (S [A"-cclib";A"-Wl,--no-as-needed"]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a workaround - disable this new linker behaviour with `-cclib -Wl,--no-as-needed`.

I guess this should be reported as a bug to mantis. Specifically, `ocamlbuild` should guarantee that options from `flag`s are inserted into command-line in the same order as they are encountered in the source (this is the case now afair), and `ocamlopt` should preserve the order of `-cclib` and `-ccopt` arguments wrt other entries on the command-line (this is NOT the case now).

Comment: Thanks this worked great. For anyone else with the problem, just make sure that these flags are before all the libraries.